# How to use cygwin bash in Android Studio terminal and start it at project directory?

Tags: android-studio, cygwin

From [this blog post](http://engineroom.teamwork.com/using-cygwins-bash-terminal-in-a-jetbrains-ide/), you can set the Android Studio Terminal to `cygwin/bash` under `Settings -> Tools -> Terminal -> Shell path`. However, the new terminal will start at your home directory (`$HOME`). You can put `cd $OLDPWD` in your `.bashrc`, as suggests in the blog post, however, that will mess up your normal cygwin session. (It will start at `/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32`)

Is it possible to start the Android Studio terminal at project directory, while normal cygwin session will start at `$HOME`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps

1. Create a `Cygwin-AndroidStudio.bat` batch file that set a custom variable. I choose `IDE`. Set `Android Studio`'s `Shell path` to

   ```
   "cmd.exe" /c "{path to}/Cygwin-AndroidStudio.bat"
   ```
2. Put the following script in `Cygwin-AndroidStudio.bat`

   ```
   @echo off
   set IDE=AndroidStudio
   C:\{path to}\cygwin64\bin\bash --login -i
   ```
3. Add the following to the end of  `~/.bashrc` under `cygwin

   ```
   if [ ! -z "${IDE}" -a "${IDE}" == "AndroidStudio" ]; then
       cd $OLDPWD;
   fi
   ```

Explanation

1. As of 2016/08/30 you need to [quote both `cmd.exe` and the `path to the script`.](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/282#issuecomment-236927851)

   - `/c` - [`Carries out the command specified by String and then stops.`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771320(v=ws.11).aspx)
2. It first set a window variable `IDE` to `AndroidStudio`. (it's an arbitrary string). It works because [`All Windows environment variables are imported when Cygwin starts.`](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-env.html)
3. If `$IDE` is defined and has the value of `AndroidStudio`, then it will `cd $OLDPWD`.

Comment: I kept getting "Couldn't create PTY" with this method on Android Studio 2.1.2 on 64-bit Windows 10. I had to make the Shell path launch cmd.exe: `cmd /K "C:\cygwin64\Cygwin-Android-Studio.bat"`

Comment: I got an error: Can't start Git: D:\git\Bash-AndroidStudio.bat Probably the path to Git executable is not valid. Fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If you like using Mintty not in Docked mode, go to Android Studio menu File - Other Settings - Default Settings and search for Terminal. At shell path you may use following :

> "D:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe" -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico D:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -l -c "cd $OLDPWD ; exec bash"

There is a little trick here. You must quotes as above otherwise you may get "java.io.IOException: Couldn't create a PTY" error message.

And keep in mind you would be required to adjust command path.

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing so it may help someone else. I managed to do it without creating any additional script or complex command line.

Under `Settings->Tools->Terminal->Shell Path`, you can set:

- To use Cygwin Bash Terminal (same used by Mintty) starting from `$HOME`:

  `<CYGWIN_INSTALL_LOCATION>\bin\bash.exe" -l`
- To use Cygwin Bash Terminal (same used by Mintty) and moving to project folder:

  `<CYGWIN_INSTALL_LOCATION>\bin\bash.exe" -l -c "cd $OLDPWD ; exec bash"`
- To use Git Bash:

  `<GIT_INSTALL_LOCATION>\bin\bash.exe" -l`

My answer is based on the other answers of this same question.. I just simplified them a bit...